# DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn Action in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I'm not really sure how to hook up the `AutoGeneratingColumn` Event using **Caliburn.Micro** Actions in WPF. I tried doing it the same way you would do `[Event Click] = ...` to no avail (it doesn't call `IDRemover`). Any guidance would be much appreciated.

**View**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyObservableCollection" AutoGenerateColumns="True" cal:Message.Attach="[Event AutoGeneratingColumn] = [Action IDRemover($eventArgs)]"></DataGrid>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public void IDRemover(System.Windows.Controls.DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "ID")
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

On a related note, is there any noticeable differences between using the **Action Parameters** vs **Message.Attach** approaches:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="DoStuff">
            <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ...}" />
        </cal:ActionMessage>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

vs

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action DoStuff(...)]" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work because Caliburn.Micro leverages the System.Windows.Interactivity for it's trigger mechanism, and that technique doesn't work with `AutoGeneratingColumn` event because it is not a RoutedEvent or a RoutedUIEvent, it is a normal .NET event.

To solve this, you can handle the event in the code-behind file of the view.

> On a related note, is there any noticeable differences between using the Action Parameters vs Message.Attach approaches ?

The latter technique, namely the Message.Attach technique was invented for those who work intensively with XAML by hand, so they don't type a lot.

The first technique, the one you called Action Parameters can be generated automatically by designers like Microsoft Expression Blend just by dragging and dropping, so if you are a designer you would love this.

Anyway the Message.Attach technique is automatically translated by Caliburn.Micro to the equivalent Action Parameters technique.

Answer (score 0):

You have attach the method like below

in View:

> AutoGenerateColumns="True"
>   cal:Message.Attach="[EventAutoGeneratingColumn] = [Action
>   ModifyDataGridColumn($this, $eventargs)];"

in Viewmodel:

> public void ModifyDataGridColumn(object sender,
>   DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e) {
>
> }

This will work only when AutoGenerate Columns is true.